# Finding Percent Error of a Fourier Series

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, continuous-fourier

Find the error as a function of n, where the error is defined as the difference between two the voltage from the Fourier series (vF (t)) and the value from the ideal function (v(t)), normalized to the maximum magnitude (Vm ):

I am given this prompt where Vm = 1 V. Below this line is the code which I have written.

I am trying to write a function to solve this question: Plot the error versus  time for n=3,n=5,n=10, and n=50. (10points). What does it look like I am doing incorrectly?

---

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

% define the signal parameters
Vm = 1;
T = 1;
w0 = 2*pi/T;

% define the symbolic variables
syms n t;

% define the signal
v1 = Vm*sin(4*pi*t/T);
v2 = 2*Vm*sin(4*pi*t/T);

% evaluate the fourier series integral
an1 = 2/T*int(v1*cos(n*w0*t),0,T/2) + 2/T*int(v2*cos(n*w0*t),T/2,T);
bn1 = 2/T*int(v1*sin(n*w0*t),0,T/2) + 2/T*int(v2*sin(n*w0*t),T/2,T);
a0 = 1/T*int(v1,0,T/2) + 1/T*int(v2,T/2,T);

% obtain C by substituting n in c[n]
nmax = 100;
n = 1:nmax;
a = subs(an1);
b = subs(bn1);


% define the time vector
ts = 1e-2; % ts is sampling the
t = 0:ts:3*T-ts;

% directly plot the signal x(t)
t1 = 0:ts:T-ts;
v1 = Vm*sin(4*pi*t1/T).*(t1<=T/2);
v2 = 2*Vm*sin(4*pi*t1/T).*(t1>T/2).*(t1<T);
v = v1+v2;
x = repmat(v,1,3);

% Now fourier series reconstruction
N = [3];

for p = 1:length(N)
for i = 1:length(t)
for k = N(p)  
x(k,i) = a(k)*cos(k*w0*t(i)) + b(k)*sin(k*w0*t(i));
end
% y(k,i) = a0+sum(x(:,i)); % Add DC term
end

end

z = a0 + sum(x);

figure(1);
plot(t,z);

%Percent error
function [per_error] = percent_error(measured, actual)
per_error = abs(( (measured - actual) ./ 1) * 100);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the forum is helping with specific technical questions, not doing your homework.